# Изменение позиции UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone, uiview

Всем привет! У меня есть UIView и я не могу изменить её позицию (координаты). Я пробую это: `_playerMapView.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, 50, 50);`

Мне надо это для того, чтобы изменять местоположение UIView с анимацией. Я пробую вот так вот и оно не работает:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
    _playerMapView.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, 50, 50);
}];
```

Пожалуйста, помогите мне сделать изменение позиции с анимацией

Comment: а без анимации работает?

Comment: скорее всего _playerMapView = nil, такое бывает, например, если переменная не привязана в InterfaceBuilder

Comment: Всё привязано и нет, без анимации не работает. Я нарыл инфу, что таким обращом нельзя изменить, если юзаешь autolayout. Но выхода так и не нашел

Comment: Зависит от того где ты вызываешь этот код, в каком потоке и тд

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
     CGRect viewNewFrame = _playerMapView.frame;
    viewNewFrame.origin.y += 100;
    _playerMapView.frame = viewNewFrame;
}];
```

Второй вариант Вы используете `autolayout` и Ваше вью имеет конкретное положение на экране. Тогда вам надо сделать `IBOutlet` для `constraint` и менять непосредственно `constraint`. Примерно так:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
   constraint.constant += 40;
}];
```

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22110084/608343) можете посмотреть как это сделать.